# spotfire - How to refresh the report with current week

Tags: date, refresh, spotfire

spotfire - How to refresh the report with current week whenever the file is open.

I have a report which contains a column with week number like (2017-49) and whenever this report is opened or refreshed it should show current week data.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [limit data using custom expressions](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire/6.5.1/doc/html/ncfe/ncfe_details_on_limit_data_using_expression.htm) for your visualization, this expression should work...

```
if(left([WeekColumn,4) = max(left([WeekColumn,4)) over (AllPrevious([WeekColumn])) and right([WeekColumn],2) = max(right([WeekColumn],2)) over (AllPrevious([WeekColumn])),TRUE,FALSE)
```

You could also split this column into Year and Week columns to make it easier.

Create Calculated Columns...

```
left([WeekColumn,4) as [TheYear]
right([WeekColumn],2) as [WeekNumber]
```

Then you could do a similar comparision